# Sincronizar itens nas comboboxes em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, entity-framework-6, mvvm

Já faz algum tempo que tento imaginar um modo de como conseguir sincronizar uma combobox com outra. Estou querendo sincronizar comboboxes em tempo de execução. Quando o usuário selecionar uma categoria na combobox, dependendo da sua escolha, a combobox subcategoria irá mostrar as subcategorias da categoria selecionada.

Estou usando WPF e C# com EntityFramework 6.

Na minha aplicação, eu consigo ler na minha ViewModel o que foi selecionado na comboBox na View. Queria saber como faço para atualizar, dinamicamente,  uma combobox depedendo do que foi selecionado em uma outra combobox, utilizando o padrão MVVM. Seguem trechos do código:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbCategoria" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding NomeCategorias}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding NomeCategoria}"
          Width="175" />


<ComboBox Name="cbSubCtg" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding NomeSubCategorias}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding NomeSubCategoria}"
          Width="175" />
```

Como podem ver, lá na minha ViewModel eu guardo o que lido na ComoboBox `cbCategoria` na variável `NomeCategoria`.

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Estou usando este site para eu ter uma idéia (http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox-wpf), mas não estou sabendo como faço para conseguir pegar o que foi lido na primeira combobox .

Comment: Faz tempo que não trabalho com WPF, você já tentou usar o evento `SelectionChanged` do combo? Estou escrevendo um resposta que usa ele, mas não sei se é esse seu problema.

Comment: @jbueno Eu até consegui um exemplo falando isso, mas acho que não fica legal, pois, na minha cabeça, vou ter que colocar lógica no code behind da view. Acho que a solução do meu problema irá utilizar sim o `SelectionChanged`, mas não será só isso. Eu acho... rsrsrs

Comment: Meu problema está sendo em como atualizar isso em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema! Usei o evento `SelectedChanged` na ComboBox que "comanda" na segunda. Agora estou conseguindo atualizar dinamicamente a segunda ComboBox. Segue o código:

```
private void cbCategoria_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cbCategoria = sender as ComboBox;
            int ctgId = -1;
            string temp = string.Empty;
            ObservableCollection<string> listaCtg;

            nomeCtg = cbCategoria.SelectedItem as string;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Sub categoria lida no handler {nomeCtg}");

            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                // Procura o nome da categoria selecionada na ComboBox
                var categoria = from x in db.Categorias
                                where x.CategoriaNome.Equals(nomeCtg)
                                select x;

                foreach (var p in categoria) { ctgId = p.CategoriaId; }

                // Procura o Id correspondente com a das categorias
                var subCtg = from x in db.SubCategorias
                             where x.Categoria.CategoriaId == ctgId
                             select x;

               listaCtg = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                foreach (var p in subCtg)
                {
                    temp = p.SubCtgNome;
                    listaCtg.Add(temp);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Subcategoria aaaa {temp}");
                }
            }

            cbSubCtg.ItemsSource = listaCtg;                        
        }
```

Sei que ainda precisa de alguns ajustes, mas este exemplo dará idéia para outros membros desta comunidade. Espero que alguém contribuia com qualquer coisa, ainda dá para melhorar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço de outra forma. Eu faça um `Binding` do segundo `ComboBox` no primeiro. Suponha que o `ItemsSource` do primeiro combo é `List<Categorias>` e cada item dessa lista tem um `List<SubCategorias>`

As classes seriam assim

```
public class Categoria 
{
   public int CodigoCategoria { get; set; }
   public string NomeCategoria { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategoria 
{
   public int CodigoSubCategoria { get; set; }
   public int CodigoCategoria { get; set; }
   public string NomeSubCategoria { get; set; }
}
```

O Binding seria assim:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboGrupo" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding CodigoCategoria, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="CodigoCategoria" 
          DisplayMemberPath="NomeCategoria" />


<ComboBox x:Name="cboSubGrupo"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cboGrupo, Path=SelectedItem.SubCategorias, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CodigoSubGrupo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="CodigoSubCategoria" 
          DisplayMemberPath="NomeSubCategoria" />
```

Você precisa fazer o carregamento do primeiro `ComboBox`. Segue um exemplo com EntityFramework.

```
public void Carregar(){
  // selecionar as categorias no banco incluindo as subcategorias
  List<Categorias> categorias = db.Categorias
                                  .Include(cat => cat.SubCategorias)
                                  .ToList();
  cboGrupo.ItemsSource = categorias;
}
```

Desta forma, ao alterar uma categoria no primeiro `ComboBox`, automaticamente mudam as subcategorias.

Comment: Gostei muito da sua abordagem, me parece que está mais perto do MVVM! Irei usar na minha aplicação. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Tentei usar na minha aplicação, mas não entendi muito como funciona. Vc poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Faço um binding do ItemsSource do segundo combo no primeiro combo, para a propriedade SelectedItem. Essa propriedade é um objeto do tipo Categoria, e esse objeto tem uma lista de SubCategorias. Como o modo desse binding é TwoWay, quando você muda um item no primeiro combo, já atualiza o ItemsSource do segundo. É necessário adicionar o Include ou join na consulta.

Comment: Interessante. Queria saber se o método `public void Carregar()` esta na ViewModel ou se está no CodeBehind?

Comment: Ele está no Behind da View pois precisa acessar o combobox, mas se quisesse deixar na ViewModel, o ItemsSource do primeiro grupo seria um Binding pra sua coleção da ViewModel. As duas formas funcionam.